# Angular 6 & PWAs

Tags: node.js, angular

I need help with Angular 6 & PWAs. Currently, I am learning Angular 6 and am having difficulty with PWAs. I have read some webpages at angular.io about PWAs.

My configuration is:
OS: Ubuntu Linux 20.04 (64 bit)
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.22.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10

I installed PWA library using ng add and the output is included below.

```
$ng add @angular/pwa
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/pwa@0.1100.2
added 42 packages from 71 contributors and audited 1397 packages in 16.097s

48 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 32 vulnerabilities (17 low, 3 moderate, 12 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

When I install these Angular packages, sometimes, there are warnings about missing/previous versions of dependencies. These, I ignore. However, for @angular/pwa, I see an error (the last line of the above output).

I see no ngsw-config.json file, either. So, may be, @angular/pwa is not installed. But, when I look at Angular version, I see:

```
$ng -v
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.22.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/pwa                      0.1100.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.9
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.0.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.16.4
```

Is that version of @angular/pwa the right one? Is this version of @angular/pwa compatible with Angular 6? Am I missing any dependencies?

Any idea what's going on here? I am kind of lost here. Any help/insight is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The version of `@angular/pwa` you have installed is the latest. Angular 6 is 5 major versions *behind* that. You need to install the version of the library that will work the version of Angular you are on. Or, learn on the latest version of Angular rather than an old version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that my installed version (Angular 6) is behind the current version of Angular is 10/11. I was hoping PWA package be backwards compatible. May be, it is not; not a problem. So, where can I find PWA package that works with Angular 6? My first place to look should be npmjs. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I visited npmjs.com and I see @angular/pwa has close to 300 previous versions listed. As per Wikipedia, Angular 6 was released in May 2018. So, I looked at @angular/pwa versions listed 2 years ago; version 0.13.9 seems to be good candidate to install and may work with Angular 6. Any comments on that?